# Unable to install chrominum-browser in ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: 14.04, networking, apt, software-center, chromium

i am unable to install chromium-browser in ubuntu-14.04.4.

log

```
vave@vave-Lenovo-G500:~$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
[sudo] password for vave: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
Suggested packages:
webaccounts-chromium-extension unity-chromium-extension adobe-flashplugin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n
The following packages will be upgraded:
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 74.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 307 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe chromium-browser amd64 60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe chromium-browser-l10n all 60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-l10n_60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
vave@vave-Lenovo-G500:~$
```

I have tried to install the chromium through Ubuntu software center, but it does'nt work, its stating

```
Failed to download package files
check your internet connection
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-l10n_60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.14.04.1190_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
```

As my internet connection is active it was prompting no internet connection,So please help me how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance

As Tom suggested, i tried sudo apt update ,  but still facing same problem, log when i tried sudo apt update

log

```
vave@vave-Lenovo-G500:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for vave: 
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [142 kB]         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,955 B]
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                

Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [405 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [63.0 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6,331 B] 
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [189 kB]    
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [3,215 B]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,747 B]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Fetched 953 kB in 4s (215 kB/s)             
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
vave@vave-Lenovo-G500:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt update`. Old versions of packages tend to be removed from the repositories when new versions are put up, so you need to redownload the list of current versions -- this is what `apt update` does.

The software center is just a graphical program which does the same things the `apt` command line programs do, so it normally gives the same errors.

Comment: HI Tom, thanks for ur reply. i tried sudo apt update, but it does not working, can u see the updated post

Comment: Oh dear. I'm sorry, I've got no idea what's going on there. Perhaps there was a bad update to the security repo (it did get updated again shortly after you tried according to its http headers -- try again?) although it's weird that all those others are failing (do they normally?) If it's still a problem maybe there's some cache you need to delete or something.